# Implementation of exp function in C using Taylor Series expansion

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, mathematics, numerical-methods

I am trying to write code to calcultate *e*<sup>*x*</sup> using:

$$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + \cdots $$

This is the code I have, which works for small values of `x`.
Please do not pay attention to the variable `e`, specifically to the fact that user enters it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    double x0,x1,e,x,sum=0.0;
    int n=0;
    scanf("%lf %lf",&x,&e);
    x1=1;
    do{
        sum+=x1;
        x0=x1;
        x1=(x/++n)*x0;
    }
    while(x1/x0>e);

    printf("sum=%lf, \nexp=%lf",sum,exp(x));
    return 0;
}
```

For input `50 0.00001` number of decimal places for e doesn't matter.
it generates:

```
sum=5184705528587076239360.000000, 
exp=5184705528587072045056.000000
```

For input `21 0.00000001`:

```
sum=1318815734.483214, 
exp=1318815734.483215
```

The difference only increases as `x` increases. 
I assume that condition is wrong but see no other way of doing it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Does your code do what you would like? I'm a little confused by your sample inputs.

Comment: @SirPython In output of my program sum= is what my code generates, exp= is what math.h function exp() returns. My code works fine for values of x less than 21. After that difference between these two functions increases as x increases

Comment: @SirPython In input: first number is x, the exponent to which e (2.718) is raised, second number is precision and is used for do-while condition, to end calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Termination condition not correct

To get the precision you request, you should stop the loop when `x1 <= e`, not when `x1 / x0 <= e`.  If you do that, you can now get rid of `x0` because it no longer serves a purpose.  I adjusted your program to use the new termination condition and it gave me the results I believe you are looking for.  I also renamed `e` to `precision` because it was confusing for a variable to be named `e` when it didn't actually hold the value of the constant \$e\$.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    double x1,precision,x,sum=0.0;
    int n=0;
    scanf("%lf %lf",&x,&precision);

    // Sums: 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + x^4/4! + x^5/5! + ...
    //
    // To get an approximation of e^x.
    //
    // Stops when the next term to add becomes smaller than precision.
    x1=1;
    do {
        sum += x1;
        x1  *= (x/++n);
    } while (x1 > precision);

    printf("sum=%lf,\nexp=%lf\n",sum,exp(x));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have tested it now on ideone and get the same answers as before. If I change type 'double' to 'long double' I get different answer than before, but just as wrong.

Comment: @BojanPavlović Must be rounding errors.  On my x86 based machine, I get the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Your computation is numerically unsound.

**Long answer:**

The termination condition looks funny indeed. From a pure mathematical standpoint `x1/x0` is equal to `x/n`, so the condition actually means `x/n > e`, and one would expect the loop to run until `n = x/e`, in your case to `5000000`. However, the unfriendly nature of floating point strikes again, and the loop breaks much earlier, at `n = 539`. Upon loop termination the debugger shows that `x1` is literally `0`. For the record, `x0` at this point is `4.94E-324`, and on the next iteration `double` ran out of mantissa bits.

It may look inconceivable that numbers as small as `4.94E-324` may significantly affect the result. In fact your problems start much earlier than that.

Look how terms of the sequence behave: they grow while `n` is less then `x`, and start decreasing after that. The maximum is obviously achieved at \$n \approx x\$, and is equal to \$\frac{x^x}{x!} \approx \frac{x^x}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}\$ (by Stirling approximation). That is, for \$x = 50\$ the 50'th term is just 1/17'th of the result, and the accumulated sum is already in order of `E21` of magnitude. The terms meanwhile start to decrease, and you find yourself in a very unfortunate situation:

***you add small values to large ones***.

To add two floating point values, the summator must align them to the same exponent. This means that the smaller value inevitably loses some bits of mantissa. There goes precision, and what's even worse, the whole mantissa may disappear: that is from the certain `n` terms stop to contribute whatsoever. For `x = 50` underflow happen at `n = 119`, and the first completely lost term is about `269909`. Considering further lost terms, that it is quite in line with the `9437184` error you've got.

**Solution:**

The huge intermediate result defeats small terms one by one. Together they can defend. Start from the small numbers (that is large `n`) and work your way down to `n = 0`. The [Horner schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) was specifically designed to deal with issues you are facing.

Comment: Right now I don't have time to look this with more attention, but I am going to look this when I finish with exams.